# Java Object mapping framework working with builder pattern

Tags: java, mapping, dozer, mapstruct, modelmapper

Is there any class mapping framework which works with builders? I would like to keep some of my classes immutable and avoid multiple constructors - the Builder Pattern comes to the rescue. However I can't any mapping framework which would use builder automatically instead of getters/setters.

Comment: I'm not sure about your exact requirements but Project Lombok might be worth a look...

Answer (score 3):

I got the following working with `Lombok` and `ModelMapper`. See: http://modelmapper.org/getting-started/

```
public class MyService {
     private ModelMapper modelMapper;

     public MyService(){
         this.modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
         this.modelMapper.getConfiguration()
            .setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT)
            .setDestinationNamingConvention(LombokBuilderNamingConvention.INSTANCE)
            .setDestinationNameTransformer(LombokBuilderNameTransformer.INSTANCE);
     }

     public OutputDTO aMethod(final InputDTO input){
          return modelMapper.map(input, OutputDTO.OutputDTOBuilder.class).build(); 
     }
}
```

Where `LombokBuilderNamingConvention` is:

```
import org.modelmapper.spi.NamingConvention;
import org.modelmapper.spi.PropertyType;

public class LombokBuilderNamingConvention implements NamingConvention {

    public static LombokBuilderNamingConvention INSTANCE = new LombokBuilderNamingConvention();

    @Override
    public boolean applies(String propertyName, PropertyType propertyType) {
        return PropertyType.METHOD.equals(propertyType);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Lombok @Builder Naming Convention";
    }

}
```

And `LombokBuilderNameTransformer` is:

```
import org.modelmapper.spi.NameTransformer;
import org.modelmapper.spi.NameableType;


public class LombokBuilderNameTransformer implements NameTransformer {

    public static final NameTransformer INSTANCE = new LombokBuilderNameTransformer();

    @Override
    public String transform(final String name, final NameableType nameableType) {
        return Strings.decapitalize(name);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Lombok @Builder Mutator";
    }
}
```

And `OutputDTO` can look like:

```
@Builder // Has .builder() static method
@Value // Thus immutable
public class OutputDTO {
   private String foo;
   private int bar;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily done with MapStruct and using a custom naming strategy for builders.

Have a look [here](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#_custom_accessor_naming_strategy) in the documentation how to use Custom Accessor naming strategy.

Your mappings then need to look like:

```
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {

    default Immutable map(Source source) {
        return mapToBuilder(source).build();
    }

    Immutable.Builder mapToBuilder(Source source);
}
```

Within MapStruct we are already working on a feature that would support out of the box support for builders. You can follow [this](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/782) issue for more details.

### Update

MapStruct now (since 1.3.0.Beta1) has out of the box support for Immutables. This means that the mapper before can be written like:

```
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {

    Immutable map(Source source);
}
```

The assumption is that there is a public static method without parameters in `Immutable` that returns the builder

Answer (score 0):

Uing `Lombok` and `ModelMapper` configure as:

```java
ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
modelMapper.getConfiguration()
           .setFieldMatchingEnabled(true)
           .setFieldAccessLevel(AccessLevel.PRIVATE);
```

By default ModelMapper uses only public setter method to map. When the class annotated with Lombok builder annotation it made the setter method as private. So to allow the ModelMapper to use the private setter method we need to add the above configureation.

OR

```java
    Configuration builderConfiguration = modelMapper.getConfiguration().copy()
    .setDestinationNameTransformer(NameTransformers.builder())
    .setDestinationNamingConvention(NamingConventions.builder());

    modelMapper.createTypeMap(MyEntity.class, MyDto.MyDtoBuilder.class, builderConfiguration);
```

where MyEnity class is:

```
   @Data
    private static class MyEntity {
        private Long id;
        private String name;
        private String value;
    }
```

and builder class is:

```
    @Data
    @Builder
    private static class MyDto {
        private final Long id;
        private final String name;
        private final String value;
    }
```

click [here](https://github.com/modelmapper/modelmapper/issues/265#issuecomment-410216912) for detail